# process terminates before python code execution

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asynchronous

I have a .net core application and I created a process to run my .bat file which includes commands for a python script extracting gabor features from a video. I want to hold the program until python code finishes(until all features are extracted)

I want to fully extact featues before I return to View(info).However, instead of waiting for the python script, code directly goes to return statment

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> ShowVideo(VideoInfo info)
        {
            info.name = info.url;
            string path = "/videos/" + info.url;
            info.url = path;
            info.possibleVideoList = GenerateVideoDropDown();

            await ExtractFramesAndGenerateSubtitles(info);

            return View(info);
        }
```

```
        public async Task ExtractFramesAndGenerateSubtitles(VideoInfo info)
        {
            string videPath = Path.Combine(Environment.WebRootPath, "videos/") + info.name;
            var outputPath = "frames";
            string pathName = info.possibleVideoList[info.name];

            //Move file to the correct location so the Gabor feature extraction code can use
            ChangeFileNameAndMove(videPath);

            // TODO: Can be deleted later
            //Exctract frames
            GenerateFrames(pathName, outputPath);

            //Run the Gabor feature extraction
            ExecuteCommandSync("runGabor.bat");

        }
```

```
        public async Task ExecuteCommandSync(object command)
        {
            var timeoutSignal = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =
                new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + command);

            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
           
            procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
            //proc.Start();
            if (proc.Start())
            {
                proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
                proc.BeginErrorReadLine();

                await proc.WaitForExitAsync(timeoutSignal.Token);
                //allow std out to be flushed
                await Task.Delay(100);
            }
            // Get the output into a string
            string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `await` before your  "ExecuteCommandSync("runGabor.bat");"
like below :

```
 await ExecuteCommandSync("runGabor.bat");
```